# VB.NET question. Linq Support?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq

Does VB.NET have LINQ support? I was discussing VB vs C# tonight and I was told that VB is different because it does not handle web services as well as C# and that it does not support linq. Is this true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[VB.NET definitely supports LINQ syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb688088.aspx). As far as web services are concerned I see no relation with LINQ.

Comment: No relation with LINQ, it just was another point of discussion as a difference between the two.

Comment: `VB is different because it does not handle web services as well as C#` - this means nothing. The person that used this as argument to defend C# against VB.NET should have provided more detailed arguments.

Comment: Agreed, i'm not sure how that would even be the case, they both compile down to IL anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, VB supports LINQ:

- Its query expressions are actually richer than C#'s, in that there are various LINQ operators which are directly supported where you'd have to call the extension method directly in C#
- It supports using extension methods as well, so you can still do things that the query expressions can't express

One area it *does* fall down on a bit is the conciseness of lambda expressions: from what I remember, VB9 didn't support anonymous functions with full bodies, and even in VB10 it ends up being wordier than C#.

I haven't used web services from VB, but I would be wary of accepting the truth of the claim that it doesn't handle them as well as C# if the source is the same one that told you it doesn't support LINQ...

Answer (score 2):

You have received answers pertaining to the LINQ part of your question, so I won't cover that again. It sounds like a very general statement to say that VB.NET does not handle web services as well as C#.

I will be honest I am not a VB.NET fan, but I have needed to used it quite a bit over the years and I have never come across any specific weakness in VB.NET when it comes to web services. And that is for both ASMX and the WCF tooling.

Answer (score 1):

Working with [WCF in VB.NET](http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/advanced/introduction-to-wcf-vb.aspx) is just as easy as in C#, the same with ASMX Web Services.

Answer (score 0):

Only LINQ limitation VB.Net had prior to .Net 4.0 framework was that you could not call a void method inside your lambda statement. E.g. Because lambdas started with the "Function" keyword in VB, the compiler required your method to return a value. But that all changed with 4.0 framework. You can now use the "Sub" keyword to begin your lambda statement. So it's pretty much a moot point, just something to be aware of in-case you run into problems using LINQ in a pre-4.0 app.